# Format Nullable DataTime in a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters, ivalueconverter

In a WPF application, i display data in a datagrid.
In this datagrid there is some DateTime value.

Where DateTime are not getting set, it displays 01/01/0001, it's ok because DateTime are not nullable.

In this case, i would like to display " - " .

I think i need to use a converter.

**I tried this :**

using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Windows.Data;

```
namespace Phoenix_CRM
{
    public class Converter
    {
    }

    public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return "--/--/----";

            DateTime returnVal;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out returnVal))
            {
                if (returnVal != DateTime.MinValue)
                    return returnVal;
                else
                    return "--/--/----";
            }
            else
                return "--/--/----";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return DateTime.MinValue;

            DateTime val;
            if (value.ToString() == "--/--/----")
                return DateTime.MinValue;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val))
                return val;
            else
                return DateTime.MinValue;
        }

    }

}
```

**I added this on my XAML :**

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:myNameSpace"
```

**On after :**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{ Binding Path= dDate,StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm},Converter={converter:Converter.DateConverter}}" Header="  Date  " Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My code don't compile because of the

```
Converter={converter:Converter.DateConverter}}
```

Anyone could help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the converter you have to define it as a resource and use that resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converter:DateConverter x:Key="DateConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Usage:

```
Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}
```

See [this tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks :) The code compile ! Nevertheless, i have an XamlParseException , with InnerException : Unable to find the ressource named "DateConverter"

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni: Try putting the resource in the Resources collection of the window or user control instead of the data grid.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <converter:DateConverter x:Key="DateConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path= dDate,StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm},Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" Header="  Date  " Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```